# What's the best way to share a development environment across a team?

Tags: git, development-environment, environment, tooling

I am on a team working on embedded software. As a result, we have many building, testing, and debugging tools that are part of our development environment along with a couple IDEs that are configured to use them. We are looking for a good solution to quickly set up new developers with the tools and environment they need.

Currently, our solution is a zip with portable versions of all the programs in it using relative paths wherever possible. This works okay, but making small changes (like adding a new extension to an IDE) requires sending an entirely new 1.5 GB zip file out to everyone. It seems like there must be a better way.

We tried putting our development environment in Git with Git LFS, which seems to work okay, but for some reason after cloning the repository, pretty much everything works except for Eclipse (pretty sure it's an issue with Git converting line endings). I feel like this might not be the best solution, and I'm interested in hearing what other people might be using to solve this problem.

Comment: Might be overkill but have you considered tools like [Chef](https://docs.chef.io/)? You basically specify what tools you need, along with installation options.

Comment: Looks interesting, and expensive. I'll take a closer look though, thank you.